# Finding the overlapped shaded region (Quiz from facebook)

Tags: geometry

> Here is [the problem](https://ibb.co/hVsHLQx). As the given figure link, the figure isn't
> drawn to scale. How to find the shaded area?

**Attempt:**
My idea is draw an inscribed square (inside the shaded region). The diagonal is $8\text{ cm}$, then the side of the square is $4\sqrt 2\text{ cm}$. But then i realized something wrong is going on here, because when the rectangle has less height, the base and the height of the shaded region seems different, meaning the inscribed rectangle is not a square and i can't determine the angle of the chord.

How to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

My answer is approximately $43 \text{cm}^2$ but i'm not sure about it. My friend's answer is approximately $40.8 \text{cm}^2$

Comment: Could you use trigonometry?

Comment: @Moti i could. Anyway, i got the area is approximately $43\text{ cm}^2$. But i doubt it, since it's different from my friend's answer.

Comment: Will a GeoGebra measure satisfy you?

Comment: @Moti depends. Actually i want to know "how to solve that" instead of "the answer of this quiz". Anyway, but i still need the answer just for cross checking my answer.

Comment: You have enough rep to load the graphic.  Why didn't you?  -1  If you have an answer you should post it, because it is much easier to check something than to redo the work.  I wish I could -1 again.

Comment: Your answer is right.

Comment: @RossMillikan -1 just bcz of that? Don't even vote cz ur not helping. Biggest mistake asking here. People on this site are very arrogant and cruel.  and easy to bully this kind of question.  I know you're smart, but you shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shaded area comprises 2 sectors (left and right) 2 isosceles triangles (top and bottom).
[image]
$$A_{shaded}=2(A_{sector}+A_{triangle} )    $$
$$A_{sector}=2a\pi r^2 / 360$$
$$A_{triangle}=3b$$
$$a=sin^{-1}(3/4)   $$
$$b=4 cos(a)   $$
Putting that all together with $r=4$ gives approx area of $43cm^2$